# How to step through evaluate function in M

Tags: powerquery, m

Is there a way to step through a custom function written in M to evaluate the results line by line?  This would be similar to using F8 to step through code in Visual Basic, or using the Evaluate tool from the Formulas ribbon within Excel.

I have written a function that's not giving an error, but it's not returning the results that I expected either. It consists of multiple steps to manipulate a text string into another string, and I'm not exactly sure where it's going wrong - I need a way to step through each line and see what it's doing, so I can pinpoint the problem and fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent of F8 for M code. The best way to analyze what it's doing is to recreate the function as a query with sample parameters and step through the Applied Steps pane in the query editor. You have to give it something to work with to see what's going on. It's fine if your example references other parameters as long as somewhere in the process you pick your parameter(s) to produce an instantiated table/list/value/column (or whatever your function takes as input) that you want to use for analysis.

Comment: Thanks Alexis - I like power query in many aspects, but it really seems like the focus has been primarily on the simple use through the GUI, and the advanced/programming stuff has been a second-though with the development team. I hope the programming side gets more attention in the future.  Simple things like an in-context syntax checker, auto capitilization correction, and ability to step through (i.e. when using the "show error" button or "deep dive" into step in a query.

Comment: Yep. The query editor is still pretty immature. They fairly recently added Intellisense, which is great, but have a way to go if it's to be a robust development environment.

Comment: I've voted for and added a few suggestions to the PowerQuery/Power BI UserVoice "ideas" community.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, you have such function:

```
    (tbl as table, col as text) =>
let
    i = Table.AddIndexColumn(tbl, "i", 0, 1),
    add = Table.AddColumn(i, "new",  each Table.Column(i, col){[i]}*10),
    del = Table.RemoveColumns(add, "i")
in
    del
```

Then you may add steps for each parameter and comment out first line:

```
//(tbl as table, col as text) =>
let
    tbl = #table(3,List.Zip({{"a".."d"},{1..4},List.Numbers(10,4,10)})),
    col = "Column3",
    i = Table.AddIndexColumn(tbl, "i", 0, 1),
    add = Table.AddColumn(i, "new",  each Table.Column(i, col){[i]}*10),
    del = Table.RemoveColumns(add, "i")
in
    del
```

After debugging you may comment out parameter steps:

```
(tbl as table, col as text) =>
let
//    tbl = #table(3,List.Zip({{"a".."d"},{1..4},List.Numbers(10,4,10)})),
//    col = "Column3",
    i = Table.AddIndexColumn(tbl, "i", 0, 1),
    add = Table.AddColumn(i, "new",  each Table.Column(i, col){[i]}*10),
    del = Table.RemoveColumns(add, "i")
in
    del
```

Comment: Aleksei, this won't work for my code, as each parameter in the code references one or more previous parameters. I'll post code later if it helps, but I'm less interested in a specific solution for troubleshooting this piece of code, as a general way to analyze M code line by line.

Comment: I get it. AFAIK there is no such tool at the moment.